# How to set specific array elements to null, then move those elements to the end of the array

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, methods

I know that an ArrayList would do this job much more simple but this is just for arrays so I'm stuck with it.

This is my method so far:

```
public boolean remove( String name) {
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<counter; i++) {
        if (friends[i].equals(name)) {
            friends[i]=null;
            for (int j = i; j > counter; j++) {
                friends[j] = friends[j+1];
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The result I want is:

```
String[] friends = {"Sean", "James", "Andrew", "Garfield", "Patrick"};
myfriends.remove("James");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(friends));
```

console output: `Sean, Andrew, Garfield,Patrick, null`

Answer (score 1):

This is where using a debugger would be useful.

I would change `j > counter` to `j < counter` and set `friends[counter-1] = null;` at the end, no point setting `friends[i] = null;` as the first thing you are going to do is overwrite it.

NOTE: You code assumes there is no duplicates.

Comment: Haha! ofc it should be j < counter.... I have been testing so much and when I came up with this I thought that I had solved it and when it didnt work I went to Stack! and my arrow was the only thing that was wrong... Thanks Peter!

Comment: @JohnBanana in your debugger you would be able to see that the code is never entering the loop.

Comment: what do you mean, never entering the loop?

Comment: @JohnBanana the condition is never true, so the code will not enter the loop.